# How can we compute log values of numbers less than 1...? using java

Tags: java, math, imagej, fiji

I am in a situation that I need to calculate something like log(1/1400). I have tried Math.log method in java but no luck. actually how can we calculate something like this in java? Math.log1p also I have tried since it give the log value of 1+x which x is the small number no luck at all. But when we use scientific calculator we can calculate log(1/1400) or ln(1/1400) easily.?

Comment: Worth bearing in mind that `log(1/x) == -log(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

You get 0 when divide 1/1400, because java use integer division when arguments are ints.

```
Math.log(((double) 1)/1400);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Math.log(double d)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log-double-) to compute the value for all real numbers greater than 0. Your problem is that you perform integer division when you divide an integer by an integer directly.

`double val = 1/1400;` will evaluate to 0.
`double val = ((double)1)/2;` will evaluate to the true value of 0.5.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got the point. Thank you for the explanation.!